# How to update the list view using LINQ query (sharepoint 2007)

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2007

How to update the list view using LINQ query (sharepoint 2007):

```
SPList taskList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["List1"];
SPList branchList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["List2"];

var taskListItems = from SPListItem tItem in taskList.Items
                    join SPListItem IItem in branchList.Items on tItem["Branch"].ToString().Split(new string[]{";#"},StringSplitOptions.None)[1] equals IItem.Title.ToString()
                    where IItem.Title.ToString() == "Kazan"
                    select tItem.Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2007 does not support Linq (.net 3.5) out of the box, i guess you are using a template??

You will need to follow a guide to get it setup:

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/09/22/how-to-get-up-and-running-with-net-3-5-in-your-sharepoint-environment.aspx

Then maybe this guide will help you build your query

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/09/24/how-to-use-linq-and-the-net-3-5-framework-with-sharepoint-to-retreive-sharepoint-list-items.aspx

Comment: I've read those articles. Query is work, but how  to update the List View ?

Comment: which list view? a SPView? you can not assign a Linq query to that, it must be CAML

Comment: Yeah, SPView can only be assigned a CAML query, not a Linq statement/result.